# Can equivalence class partitioning be applied for testing an advanced search feature?

Tags: testing, ui-automation, faceted-search, advanced-search, equivalence-classes

I have a Advanced Search feature where in I first search for a key word and then i refine my search by selecting the different filters in a different category, these are multi-select check boxes.

Example: Lets say I am looking for a "Car" once I enter this in the search box and press enter i will get broad set of results. Now i need to refine my search, something like I select the check box for "Honda" & "Toyota" under manufacturer category next I have the country category where I can select "United States" it will list me all states under US now I can select "Washington" next I can refine to some city of Washington and so on....

So testing for results for all possible filter selections is very difficult. So I was wondering if the ECP design pattern can be applied for this testing ?. How can i optimize my testing ? Any examples will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably each checkbox for each car manufacturer is implemented in exactly the same way, so yes.

But I would not really describe this as "advanced search", this is more like "faceted search". (Are you testing Ebay by any chance? This sounds exactly like Ebay.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Actually this is a very common scenario in any job portal or any site like Ebay, or any shopping site...So just wanted to know what is the best way to go about testing these sort of scenarios with minimum effort, as obviously all permutation combinations are not possible to test  :)